# can't load external JS file from java class, maven application

Tags: javascript, java, maven, vaadin

I'm having a really hard time trying to load an external js file from a java class with the usual @Javascript notation, the file just won't load and I can't understand why.
This is the class where I have the annotation:

```
    package my.vaadin.project.rpc.simple.test;
    import my.vaadin.project.rpc.simple.test.client.IRpcComponentClientRpc;
    import my.vaadin.project.rpc.simple.test.client.IRpcComponentServerRpc;
    import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
    import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent;
    @JavaScript({"RpcComponent.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"})
    public class RpcComponent extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent
    {...
```

My js file sits in the same package as this class (meaning src/main/resources/my/vaadin/project/rpc/simple/test), is there anything else I need to do?
I have another class, the UI where I'm creating an object of type RpcComponent but I don't think I need that to get the js to load I don't think..Any idea?

Comment: You should add the tag vaadin, so people following that badge will see your question.

Comment: How are you running the app, from the IDE, after packaging it and deploying under tomcat, etc? Did you check to see if it gets published or packaged correctly? If you use the [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) can you see it loaded, or are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm running it under the IDE, and checking the results in chrome (dev tools). The javascript just doesn't load, no errors in the console. Curiously though, if I use the same Javascript notation under the UI class, the script is loaded.

Comment: According to [this](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-loves-javascript-components) article, your file location is correct. Try to put the JS file into the same folder your class resides. Maybe maven does something unexpected.

Comment: Hi thanks, I've just tried but no joy, the darn script ain't loading, now everything (the UI class, the RpcComponent class and the js sit here: `rpc.simple.test --> src/main/java --> my.vaadin.project.rpc.simple.test`) It still works if I call it from the MyUI.java class though...

Comment: Please check logs. There should be information why file mentioned in @Javascript annocation is not being loaded (look carefully, it is logged as INFO or WARNING during Vaadin startup)

Comment: Figured that out eventually. Basically in my UI class not only I had to create an object of MyComponent class, which I did, but I also had to add it to the UI together with other components like buttons, labels etc, like so
`layout.addComponents(label, button, myComponent);`
That did the trick. As to the Info and Warning nothing really stick out, was I supposed to look for some specific message?